# Método update Lavarel

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

Tengo una vista donde me traigo los datos para editar de cada usuario, mediante un foreach.
Me trae los datos dependiente del usuario que yo quiera... 
Mi vista:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
</div>

<table class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel-body">


            <thead style="background-color: #F9EABB">
                <th class="table-warning">ID</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Nombre</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Apellido</th>
                <th class="table-warning">ID</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Primera calificación</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Segunda calificación</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Promedio</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Tercera calificación</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Promedio Final</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Fecha del curso</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Tipo de aprobación</th>
                <th class="table-warning">Acciones</th>
                <th style="visibility:hidden" class="table-warning">idk alumno</th>
                <th style="visibility:hidden" class="table-warning">idc materia</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

    @foreach($alumnosxmat as $alumnosxm)
            @foreach($idkalificacionn as $idkalificacion)
                                    @if ($alumnosxm->idk_alumno === $alumno)


                <tr class="table-warning"> 


                    <td>{{$alumnosxm->idk_alumno}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alumnosxm->a_nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alumnosxm->a_apaterno}}</td>

                  <td>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input id="id" type="input" class="form-control" name="id"
                                value="{{$idkalificacion->id}}">
                                @if ($errors->has('id'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('id') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif

                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('primera_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">


                                <input id="primera_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="primera_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->primera_cal}}">


                                @if ($errors->has('primera_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('primera_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif

                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('segunda_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input id="segunda_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="segunda_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->segunda_cal or old('segunda_cal') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('segunda_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('segunda_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('ps_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <div class="col-xs-15">
                                <input id="ps_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="ps_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->ps_cal or old('ps_cal') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('ps_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('ps_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('tercera_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input id="tercera_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="tercera_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->tercera_cal or old('tercera_cal') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('tercera_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('tercera_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('prom_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">                 <div class="col-xs-15">
                                <input id="prom_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="prom_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->prom_cal or old('prom_cal') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('prom_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('prom_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('fecha_curso') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <div class="col-xs-18">
                                <input id="fecha_curso" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_curso" value="{{$idkalificacion->fecha_curso or old('fecha_curso') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('fecha_curso'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha_curso') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('tipo_de_aprob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <div class="col-xs-18">
                            <select id="tipo_de_aprob" type="input" class="form-control" name="tipo_de_aprob">
                                <option value="Ordinario">Ordinario</option>
                                <option value="Extraordinario">Extraordinario</option>
                            </select>


                            @if ($errors->has('tipo_de_aprob'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('tipo_de_aprob') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> <div class="form-group">              
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <center> 
                                <a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.actualizar', $idkalificacion->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Actualizar calificación</a>


                            </center>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="visibility:hidden">
                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('idk_alumno') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                          <label for="idk_alumno" class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <select  id="idk_alumno" class="form-control" name="idk_alumno">
                                        <option value="{{$alumnosxm->idk_alumno}}">{{$alumnosxm->idk_alumno}}</option> 
                                    </select>
                            @if ($errors->has('idk_alumno'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('idk_alumno') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                      </div>   
                    </td>

                    <td style="visibility:hidden">
                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('idc_materia') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                          <label for="idc_materia" class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <select  id="idc_materia" class="form-control" name="idc_materia">
                                        <option value="{{$id}}">{{$id}}</option> 
                                    </select>
                            @if ($errors->has('idc_materia'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('idc_materia') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                      </div>   
                    </td>



                </tr>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                      @endforeach   
            </tbody>

        </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>

</table>


</div>
```

Entonces para traerme los datos de un campo, lo hago así:
    value="{{$idkalificacion->prom_cal or old('prom_cal') }}"

Para llevarmelo a actualizar...

lo hago con esta linea de código:

```
 <a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.actualizar', $idkalificacion->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Actualizar calificación</a>
```

pero mi problema es que en el método actualizar, si me buscar el registro pero cuando le doy actualizar me lo deja todo en blanco.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {

$idkalificacionn=K_calificacion::find($id);
//$request->all();
$idkalificacionn->primera_cal = $request->primera_cal;
$idkalificacionn->segunda_cal= $request->segunda_cal;
$idkalificacionn->ps_cal=$request->ps_cal;
$idkalificacionn->tercera_cal=$request->tercera_cal;
$idkalificacionn->prom_cal=$request->prom_cal;
$idkalificacionn->fecha_curso=$request->fecha_curso;
$idkalificacionn->tipo_de_aprob=$request->tipo_de_aprob;
$idkalificacionn->idk_alumno=$request->idk_alumno;
$idkalificacionn->idc_materia=$request->idc_materia;
$idkalificacionn->save();   }
```

En realidad no se como hacer el request, porque en mi vista no es solo.

```
   $primera_cal
```

si no:

```
    $idkalificacion->primera_cal
```

Comment: Se debe poner de la siguiente manera:
<cod>$request->input('primera_cal');</cod>

Comment: Hola, lo hago de la siguiente manera: pero sigue sin actualizarme.. Sigo haciendo algo mal? 
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {

     $idkalificacionn=K_calificacion::find($id);
    $idkalificacionn->primera_cal = $request->input('->primera_cal');
    $idkalificacionn->segunda_cal= $request->input('segunda_cal');
    $idkalificacionn->ps_cal=$request->input('ps_cal');
    $idkalificacionn->save();  }

Comment: Solo note un error, quedando asi:

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id) {
  $idkalificacionn = K_calificacion::find($id);
  $idkalificacionn->primera_cal = $request->input('primera_cal');
  $idkalificacionn->segunda_cal = $request->input('segunda_cal');
  $idkalificacionn->ps_cal = $request->input('ps_cal');
  $idkalificacionn->save();
 }

Answer (score 0):

A que te refieres que te envia a una página en blanco? Te envia a una pagina en blanco por que en el controlador actualizas y no haces nada más, puedes agregar al final `return back();` para que te regrese a la página anterior.

Con lo de los request te enviará el valor dependiendo del name en el input, por ejemplo:

`<input type="text" name="nombre" />`

esto por el request lo podrías recibir `$request->nombre`.

Te recomiendo que veas los metodos de laravel para que no tengas que asignar variables uno por uno, en vez de eso que haces podrías simplemente hacer `$k_calificacion::update($request->all());`

En general el codigo correcto sería hacer esto:

```
public function update(Request $request, K_calificacion $calificacion)
 {
         $calificacion->update($request->all);
         return back();
 }
```

y agregar en el modelo las variables `fillable` con los campos.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En la vista usa array de valores

```
name="idkalificacion[{{$id}}}][primera_cal]"
```

y luego en el controlador puedes recogerlo así:

```
foreach ($request->idkalificacion as $calificacion) {
      dd(calificacion['primera_cal'])
}
```